# Upload image to wordpress using REST API

Tags: rest-api

I am developing API for Wordpress using REST-API. Now I am stuck at one point where I am not able to develop the API through which I can upload the image to wordpress using Rest API.

I am using Postman to test API developed for my website

Comment: kinda hard to tell you what is the problem with your code when you do not show it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload images just like your normal PHP/Wordpress file uploads.

Reference `=>` [wp_handle_upload](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload)

```
$mimes = array(
    'bmp'  => 'image/bmp',
    'gif'  => 'image/gif',
    'jpe'  => 'image/jpeg',
    'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
    'jpg'  => 'image/jpeg',
    'png'  => 'image/png',
    'tif'  => 'image/tiff',
    'tiff' => 'image/tiff'
);

$overrides = array(
    'mimes'     => $mimes,
    'test_form' => false
);

$upload = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['YOUR_INPUT_FILE_NAME_HERE'], $overrides );
remove_filter( 'upload_dir', array($this, 'change_upload_dir') );
if ( isset( $upload['error'] ) ){
    // SOME UPLOAD ERROR OCCURED
} else {
    // File uploaded successfully. 
    $uploadedFileURL = $upload['url'];
    $uploadedFileName = basename($upload['url']);
}
```

> And you can attach files in postman following way.

[image]